# How to convert MultipartFile to UTF-8 always while using CSVFormat?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, encoding, character-encoding

I am using a spring boot REST API to upload csv file MultipartFile. CSVFormat library of org.apache.commons.csv is used to format the MultipartFile and CSVParser is used to parse and the iterated records are stored into the MySql database.

```
csvParser = CSVFormat.DEFAULT
            .withDelimiter(separator)
            .withIgnoreSurroundingSpaces()
            .withQuote('"')
            .withHeader(CsvHeaders.class)
            .parse(new InputStreamReader(csvFile.getInputStream()));
```

Observation is that when the CSV files are uploaded with charset of UTF-8 then it works good. But if the CSV file is of a different format (ANSI etc.,) other than it, its encoding German and other language characters to some random symbols.

Example äößü are encoded to ����

I tried the below to specify the encoding standard, it did not work too.

```
        csvParser = CSVFormat.DEFAULT
            .withDelimiter(separator)
            .withIgnoreSurroundingSpaces()
            .withQuote('"')
            .withHeader(CsvHeaders.class)
            .parse(new InputStreamReader(csvFile.getInputStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```

Can you please advise. Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 3):

What you did `new InputStreamReader(csvFile.getInputStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)` tells the CSV parser that the content of the inputstream is UTF-8 encoded.
Since UTF-8 is (usally) the standard encoding, this is actually the same as using `new InputStreamReader(csvFile.getInputStream())`.

If I get your question correctly, this is not what you intended. Instead you want to automatically choose the right encoding based on the Import-file, right?
Unfortunatelly the csv-format does not store the information which encoding was used.
There are some libraries you could use to guess the most probable encoding based on the characters contained in the file. While they are pretty accurate, they are still guessing and there is no guarantee that you will get the right encoding in the end.

Depending on your use case it might be easier to just agree with the consumer on a fixed encoding (i.e. they can upload UTF-8 or ANSI, but not both)

Answer (score 0):

Try as shown below which worked for me for the same issue

```
new InputStreamReader(csvFile.getInputStream(), "UTF-8")
```